# Editing the preview of a link on facebook

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have launched a new website for a few days. When I copy and paste the links of adverts on Facebook, the preview is not correct, I mean that the image and the title of the advert are not displayed despite that I added the tags `<meta property = "og:title ">` and `<meta property ="og:description">`

Here is a piece of source code:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.coinemploi.com/assets/images/logo_lg.png">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="coinemploi.com">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.coinemploi.com/jobs/show/6/des-teleconseiller-tunis-h-f">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Des téléconseiller - tunis  (h/f)">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Offre d'empoi Des Téléconseiller - Tunis  (H/F) à Tunis, Tunisie - CDD / Intérim / Mission - CDI - Temps Plein - SIVP - Centre d’appels - entreprise Manwork">`

and here is how it's displayed on Facebook

[image]

Comment: The debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coinemploi.com%2Fjobs%2Fshow%2F6%2Fdes-teleconseiller-tunis-h-f complains that your SSL cert is selfsigned

Comment: And https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.coinemploi.com complains about the certificate chain. So fix that first and it should start to work